# Jenkinsfile pipeline to store artifacts to jfrog artifactory with sha checksum in filename

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

how do I store (Archive stage) artifacts to artifactory post jenkins build with SHA5 checksum in filename?

E.g. What I want as filename stored on artifactory: 
 sha__`2340ursoddpkjfsodfj0429trjw0fjosdfkjsao90024r`.h 
Artifactory checksum SHA-1: `2340ursoddpkjfsodfj0429trjw0fjosdfkjsao90024r`

```
def server = Artifactory.server 'my-jfrog-artifactoryserver'
def uploadSp = """{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "*.h",
      "target": "builds/myhfiles/"
    }
  ]
}"""


node('h-builder')
{
 {
        stage ('Archive')
        {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/*.h', fingerprint: true
            server.upload spec: uploadSp, failNoOp: true
        }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Placeholders](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-UsingPlaceholders) for this:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "(*).h",
      "target": "builds/myhfiles/{1}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Read more about File Specs greatness [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs) and [there](https://jfrog.com/blog/use-file-specs-in-your-cicd-to-get-full-control-of-your-artifacts/).

Plugin documentation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in).

Comment: This doesn't upload files and rename it to with a SHA checksum. It needs to get SHA from somewhere, what I can see when I upload manually is that it has SHA checksum in the checksum column.